# How to update values of existing keys or insert new key -values to a mongo document based on a python dictionary using pymongo?

Tags: pymongo

I have a dictionary object in python,

```
  dic = {"_id":1,
         "A":123,
         "B":234,
         "C":222}
```

and a collection in mongo that has stored the same ID document in mongo which looks like,

```
  mongodoc= {"_id":1,"A":233,"B":234,"D":999}
```

I want to update the documents in mongo directly based on the dictionary values using pymongo,

```
  mongodoc={"_id":1,"A":123,"B":234,"D":999,"C":222}
```

If the keys matches between the dictionary and mongo document, update the values else insert new key value pairs.
I tried using

```
collection.update{"_id:1",{"set"}}
```

but this needs to be given a specific keys which doesn't work for my problem statement. Not sure how to proceed.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The `$set` operator takes a dictionary which will achieve what you are looking to do:

```
collection.update_one({'_id': dic['_id']}, {'$set': dic})
```